# How would I get the text from a blank HTML page to my app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to know if there is a simple way to grab the text of a complete blank HTML page via android studio (so for an android app), and then put it as a text on my app.

I mean something like this:

You have a blank HTML page with a text such as this: https://pastebin.com/raw/Zuvfqdu9

You have a textview code such as:

```
 android:text="The page says: $WHATTHEPAGESAYS"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

You grab the text, and parse it in your textview in your android app.

Anyone maybe got a clue on how to do this?
Code that's given at current questions that are similair to this question are outdated and not working anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34332248/8089770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android textview for html from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331812/android-textview-for-html-from-url)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503817/8089770

Answer (score 0):

use JSOUP or KSOAP.
These are two libraries which read the contents of a webpage.